# How to hide <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table, hide

So I have these codes(only the necessarry parts)
this is where the button is:

```
<td id="Assault">
<button onclick="hideassault()">Assault</button>
</td>

<td id="AssaultWP">
```

all those images(which are actually buttons) are in a table-cell, and they all have the same ID

```
#AssaultWP{
display:block;
}
```

also this pretty simple css which matters

and the script, which I thought would work:

```
function hideassault() {
var hideA = document.getElementById("AssaultWP");
if (hideA.style.display === "none") {
    hideA.style.display = "block";
} else {
    hideA.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

I thought since all td has the same ID, it would hide all of them, but it actually hides the first cell only, and with that comes my question:
Shouldn't it hide all the cells if they have the same ID? What did i do wrong? Could someone help me doing it?
Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

Comment: `id` is an unique identifier. Use classes if all is the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me help, so first keep in mind you are working with an `td` but never defining its parent element which is an `table`, so that would be the first fix.

**Example:**

```
<table>
 <tr> 
   <th>Header</th> <!-- table header -->
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>data/information</td> <!-- table data/information -->
 </tr>
</table>
```

The second problem is as i commented yesterday , `id` is an unique identifier. Use classes if all is the same name.

Which then leads to the third problem, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array type object = `HTMLCollection`.

So `querySelectorAll` in this case will help you to select each element by its class name.

**Example:**

```js
function hideAssault() {
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.assault_r'), function (sh) {

  if (sh.style.display === "none") {
    sh.style.display = "table-cell"; //block , not preferred , but up to you
  } else {
    sh.style.display = "none";
  }
  
});
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    display: table-cell; /* block , not preferred , but up to you*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="hideAssault()">Assault</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault2</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault3</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault4</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault5</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault6</td>
    <td class="assault_r">Assault7</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly
Thank you so much for helping!
I'm really a beginner yet, and mainly the script part is which I'm not too good at yet unfortunatelly

Comment: @Somebody its my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Id's are meant to be unique. Use classes for this kind of situation where you have to handle multiple stuff.
I'm assuming you have given class name as 'AssaultWP'.
The js function would look like

```
function hideassault() {
  var hideA = document.getElementsByClassName("AssaultWP");
  var n = hideA.length;
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("AssaultWP")[0].style.display === "none") {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      hideA[i].style.display = "block"; 
    }
  } else {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      hideA[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gse1t9cy/10/).

Comment: Also Tried some variations of it,  none of them worked unfortunately

Comment: I'm sorry, it's getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName. Will update the answer

Comment: this returns an `HTMLCollection`, would not work, can you create a snippet showing how this would work?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Should've tried it out before posting. Anyway, I'll update the answer with a fiddle.